# Working with PowerShell Objects and Parameters

Tags: function, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create Azure AD Conditional Access policies via a script.

When I have the following block the script successfully creates the Conditional Access policy

```
$DisplayName = "Block Legacy Authentication"
$State = "enabledForReportingButNotEnforced"
$Conditions = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessConditionSet
$Conditions.Applications = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessApplicationCondition
$Conditions.Applications.IncludeApplications = "All"
$Conditions.Users = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessUserCondition
$Conditions.Users.IncludeUsers = "All"
$Conditions.Users.ExcludeGroups = $ExcludeCAGroup.ObjectId
$Conditions.ClientAppTypes = @('ExchangeActiveSync', 'Other')
$GrantControls = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessGrantControls
$GrantControls._Operator = "OR"
$GrantControls.BuiltInControls = "Block"

New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy -DisplayName $DisplayName -State $State -Conditions $Conditions -GrantControls $GrantControls
```

However when I try to set the policy via a function, it returns an error

```
function Create-ConditionalAccess {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$DisplayName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateSet('Enabled','enabledForReportingButNotEnforced','Disabled')]
        [String]$State,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Conditions,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $GrantControls
    )

     New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy -DisplayName $DisplayName -State $State -Conditions $Conditions -GrantControls $Controls 

}




$DisplayName = "Block Legacy Authentication"
$State = "enabledForReportingButNotEnforced"
$Conditions = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessConditionSet
$Conditions.Applications = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessApplicationCondition
$Conditions.Applications.IncludeApplications = "All"
$Conditions.Users = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessUserCondition
$Conditions.Users.IncludeUsers = "All"
$Conditions.Users.ExcludeGroups = $ExcludeCAGroup.ObjectId
$Conditions.ClientAppTypes = @('ExchangeActiveSync', 'Other')
$GrantControls = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessGrantControls
$GrantControls._Operator = "OR"
$GrantControls.BuiltInControls = "Block"

Create-ConditionalAccess -DisplayName $DisplayName -State $State -Conditions $Conditions -GrantControls $GrantControls
```

The error is

```
New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy : Error occurred while executing NewAzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy 
Code: BadRequest
Message: 1032: ConditionalActionPolicy validation failed due to InvalidControls.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You declare the parameter `$GrantControls` in `Create-ConditionalAccess`, but then you pass `$controls` to `New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy`

Comment: Thank you for picking up my error - a second set of eyes is great :)

Comment: Hi do you mind moving your comment to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been resolved by @Mathias R. Jessen comment, post it as an answer to close the question.

> You declare the parameter $GrantControls in Create-ConditionalAccess,
> but then you pass $controls to New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy

The solution is to modify this line of code：

```
New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy -DisplayName $DisplayName -State $State -Conditions $Conditions -GrantControls $GrantControls
```